# discord.py Error - ClientConnectorCertificateError

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, discord, discord.py, aiohttp

I have an error trying to run my python discord bot.
Here's my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return None

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('<redacted>')
```

When I run this, I get the following error code: `aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)')]`
Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection      
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)  

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\shalev\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.111407\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\shalev\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.111407\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\shalev\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.111407\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "f:\python projects\among us bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.run('<redacted>')
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 678, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 658, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 472, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 288, in static_login     
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__    
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request       
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect     
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\shalev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What OS are you running this on? Does it have any anitvirus software that could be man-in-the-middle-ing your SSL traffic?

Comment: When i checked it i had no antivirus, and I'm using windows 10

Answer (score -2):

Try updating discord.py.

```
pip install -U discord.py
```

Worked personally for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I'm using the latest version already - version 1.5.0