# How to avoid getting ClientConnectorCertificateError with discord.py on Mac

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to run a discord bot locally on my mac:

```
import discord
import os
token = token

description = '''A bot that can do more than you think'''

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description=description, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command(name='test', help='Check if the bot is added properly')
async def test(ctx):
  userid = ctx.author.id
  user = prep_mention(userid)
  print('hello')
  await ctx.send(f'{user} hello')

bot.run(token)
```

However when running this: I get this error:

```
raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')]
```

It works perfectly on replit, but I can't get it to work locally on my Mac. Any ideas?

I have already tried this but to no avail:
[discord.py Error - ClientConnectorCertificateError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145278/discord-py-error-clientconnectorcertificateerror)

the token is an actual value: havent put it on stack overflow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (\_ssl.c:1108) Discord/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411362/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-i)

Comment: yes that fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by using following command on my Mac:
replace with your own version of python
/Applications/Python\ 3.9/Install\ Certificates.command